# Sliding fly screen door size

Tags: doors, sliding-glass-door

I'm planning to add a fly screen to our sliding door entry. There's no roller track in place yet and the height in the space is 204cm. I'm hoping to find a used one online and I see a lot of them are claimed to be 204cm tall. Does anyone know what door height I should look for? Would I need something shorter than 204cm in order to push it in?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: A door with the same exact size of the opening is usually not good.  With a sliding door you have rollers that increase the size.  A door that is 204cm tall with the rollers fully extended should work.  The rollers usually have ~5 to 10cm of play.  Without rollers you want some play, maybe .25 to .5cm.